# Rationalisation of $\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-t})(1-\sqrt[3]{1-t})...(1-\sqrt[n]{1-t})}{t^{n-1}},t\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone show the steps for rationalisation of the expression. The result should be $$\frac{t^{n-1}}{2\times 3 ... \times nt^{n-1}}$$

Comment: So such a function equals $\frac{1}{n!}$? It looks hard to believe, for instance by evaluating the original function at $t=1$.

Comment: Seconded - this can't be correct as it stands; the former expression is clearly irrational when e.g. $n=2, t=\frac12$ but the latter is obviously rational.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simply false. Let $n = 2$:

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t}}{t} \neq \frac{t}{2t} = \frac12$$